# Destroy method on jQuery DatePicker removes DatePicker but when I re-instantiate a new one, the previous selected Date value is still selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I created a demo to show the issue I am having using a jQuery library called **Zebra-Datepicker**.

**Zebra-Datepicker documentation**: http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/
**Zebra-Datepicker GitHub**:  https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker

My demo shows how to:

- create a DatePicker instance,
- select a date value,
- destroy the date picker instance,
- create a new instance of the date picker,
- select a new date value....

**Problem:**

The problem is that destroying the DatePicker does not seem to destroy the previous selected date value!  So when instantiating a new DatePicker, it has the previous Date value selected instead of a new value!

I could really use some expert help as this is crucial for me to fix for my project which loads Project Task records into a Modal DIV.  My Task records all share the HTML in the DOM of a single Modal, just replacing placeholder variables for a Task and then re-setting them  when Modal is closed for the next Task to do the process over and over.

My Demo JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/Lqwfamoc/17/

If you follow these steps on my demo you will see what I mean...

1. Click on Date SPAN to reveal DatePicker calendar and click on date **2015-05-30**
2. Click **Destroy DatePicker** button
3. Click on Date Span which will then show DatePicker is missing since we destroyed it.
4. Now click on **UPDATE DatePicker to 2015-05-24** Button which will set the Date SPAN value to have a new date of 2015-05-24.  When we instantiate the DatePicker plugin again, it should grab this new date value in the SPAN and set the DatePicker to this date!
5. Now click **Build New DatePicker** button which instantiates a new DatePicker
6. Now click the Date SPAN text: **2015-05-24** to show the DatePicker Calendar again
7. You should now see that the original 30th day **2015-05-30** is selected in the DatePicker even though it **SHOULD now have our Date value of 2015-05-24** selected instead since we `destroy()` and `re-instantiated` a new DatePicker after Destroying the old one!

Apparently, the Destroy method didn't full destroy or something else is going on?  Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

**The sourcecode of the actual Zebra-Datepicker lIbrary's destroy() method:
Located here**
 https://github.com/stefangabos/Zebra_Datepicker/blob/master/public/javascript/zebra_datepicker.src.js#L1469

```
/**
 *  Destroys the date picker.
 *
 *  @return void
 */
plugin.destroy = function() {

    // remove the attached icon (if it exists)...
    if (undefined !== plugin.icon) plugin.icon.remove();

    // ...and the calendar
    plugin.datepicker.remove();

    // remove associated event handlers from the document
    $(document).unbind('keyup.Zebra_DatePicker_' + uniqueid);
    $(document).unbind('mousedown.Zebra_DatePicker_' + uniqueid);
    $(window).unbind('resize.Zebra_DatePicker_' + uniqueid);

    // remove association with the element
    $element.removeData('Zebra_DatePicker');

};
```

Comment: I don't have a solution, but just a comment  ... The repro for this problem is much simpler than you described.  No need to destroy and re-create the picker.   Simply do this: 1.) load the page, 2.) click the span to open the DatePicker, 3.) Choose 5/30/2015 in the picker, 4.) Click the button "UPDATE DatePicker SPAN val to 2015-05-24, and finally, 5.) Click the span again to open the DatePicker.  Notice the date is set to 5/30 instead of 5/24.

Comment: @RajeevGoel Thanks fpor the comment, I think you might have misunderstood just a bit (probably my fault) but I need to destroy it and re-set because I will be opening different data into a Modal.  If you follow the steps I describe, you will see that it does not update under that process and that is the process that will have to be taken when different modals are being loaded.

Comment: I understand that you need to destroy it and re-build the DatePicker for your scenario.  What I was saying is that the bug that you are reporting will reproduce (show itself) even if you don't destroy/rebuild the DatePicker.  In other words, you don't have to destroy/rebuild the DatePicker in order to witness the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem.  You need to change this:

```
$('#updateDate').on('click', function(){
    $('#task-modal-due-date-span').text('2015-05-24');
});
```

to this:

```
$('#updateDate').on('click', function(){
    $('#task-modal-due-date-span').text('2015-05-24').val('2015-05-24');
});
```

The reason is that when you rebuild a new DatePicker control, it is looking at the **value** of the span, not the **text** of the span.  (Note:  Normally you would attach a DatePicker to an "input" element, not a "span" element.)

Comment: This could be the solution to my problem so thank you!

Comment: Great, glad I could help.  Please mark my post as the Accepted Answer.  I spend a lot of time on this one.